# How to Fine tune a pre -trained Swin-Transformer for a downstream task (segmentation) for a custom data with images of size 512 in PyTorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, computer-vision

**Tl;DR: How could I access the  `pytorch`  `pre-trained` model for `Swin-Transformer` so that I could extract features from it to train it on segmentation task using `DeepLabv3+`  head on a custom data set with image sizes of 512**

I am testing [SwinTransformer backbone](https://github.com/microsoft/Swin-Transformer) with [Deeplabv3+ as head](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.02611) for semantic segmentation.

I already have the code for `Head` and it **get the features from backbone** and then process the features in different way. It is working fine for `ResNet` and `Xception`. The thing is that I want to work with pre-trained `SWIN`. Now there are many ways but each of those has it's own set of problems.

**1. Using [`timm` library for pre-trainned models`](https://github.com/rwightman/pytorch-image-models#getting-started-documentation)**

```
! pip install timm
import timm
import torch

all_swins = timm.list_models('*swin*')
print(all_swins)

model = timm.create_model('swin_large_patch4_window12_384_in22k', in_chans = 3, pretrained = True,)

print(model.default_cfg)
dummy_image = torch.randn(1,3,512,512) # create an image of size 512
model.forward_features(dummy_image) # extract features : Will result in error


new_model = timm.create_model('swin_large_patch4_window12_384_in22k', in_chans = 3, pretrained = True, img_size = 512)  # This won't work I'll explain below
```

The problem is that None of the above code work. Reason being that the model accepts here an image of size `384` but my images are of `512`. So you could change the argument `img_size` for other `CNNs` but [as the author has clarified in this question](https://github.com/rwightman/pytorch-image-models/discussions/565)

> It should work with the vit, vit_deit, vit_deit_distilled. Has not been implemented for pit, swin, and tnt yet.

**2. Using `MMcv / MMSeg` library**:
[Please open this colab notebook. I have commented and documented the part](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1oGJ8gwrfI2A8q2zTLrXhjoyMle4p_omS?usp=sharing)

**Problem**: The pre-trained weights are for only for a specific method which produced SOTA results i.e `ADE` dataset using `UperNet` backbone. I can not use it with `DeepLabv3+` on a custom dataset.

**3. [Segmentations Models Pytorch Library](https://github.com/qubvel/segmentation_models.pytorch) which uses [`timm` encoders](https://smp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/encoders_timm.html)**

Problem: Again, as it uses `timm`, so the image resolutions can't be changed.

**4. [PaddleSeg Library](https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleSeg/blob/release/2.4/docs/model_zoo_overview.md)**

It has `Swin transformer` but `Deeplabv3+` works only with `Resnet50 and 101`

**Last Resort**: In the end, I pulled up the [official code from microsoft](https://github.com/microsoft/Swin-Transformer) where I found couple of useful things:

- [configuration `yml` file](https://github.com/microsoft/Swin-Transformer/blob/main/configs/swin_large_patch4_window12_384_22kto1k_finetune.yaml)
- [Code which they use for model building `def build_model()`](https://github.com/microsoft/Swin-Transformer/blob/6ded2577413b68cbbd89f08391465788ed73030e/models/build.py#L12)
- [Code inside `def main()` which parses the arguments and builds the whole model](https://github.com/microsoft/Swin-Transformer/blob/6ded2577413b68cbbd89f08391465788ed73030e/main.py#L37)

I don't really know how to build the model changing the image size configurations. If anyone has any idea, please help.